# Expo won't build with locally installed NPM packages

Tags: expo, npm-install

I am using `expo@43.0.3` (and `expo-cli@5.0.3`) to manage my react native project and I have to install an npm package from local source:

```sh
$ npm install /path/to/mypackage
```

In my package.json the package is successfully linked via

```json
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "myPackage": "file:../../mypackage",
  ...
}
```

I can also confirm the package works when installing to a new plain node project (same node version `14.8.2`)

Now when I start expo via `expo start` and navigate to the app it does not throw any error but only a warning:

```sh
› Reloading apps
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

When using the package from registry everything builds, however.

I tried to use the [private packages section form the expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/private-npm-packages/), but they only describe how to use private packages from registry but not local.

Anything I'm missing here?

**edit**:

After resetting the expo network adapters it loads the bundle but it now says it can't find the package:

```sh
Unable to resolve module myPackage from /home/user/path/to/myPackage/file.js: myPackage could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

However, I'm not using watchman and I'm not using yarn and rmoving metro- folders from /tmp did not make a difference.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Actually, not me but the expo team: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16239

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16239) it can be solved via `npm pack`:

> run `npm pack` inside of your library and then `npm install path/to/the/packed/file.tgz` from your project

Which worked fine for the setup I described in the question.